# Sort Visual Studio-2008 Members Drop down list by member type, and not alphabetically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I work with ASP.NET/C#, and when in code-view there is a members drop down list above the text editor. Any visual studio developers with even some experience with the IDE probably know what I'm talking about. Anyway, the list displays all the members of the code-file I'm currently working with in alphabetical order. Is there any way to change that to display this list by member type?

Comment: That's something I wanted for myself a number of times. I would really appreciate an answer!